# Add a removed existing remote to a git repository

Tags: git, repository, git-remote

I accidentally performed a `git remote rm <remote_repo_name>` :(
Will a `git remote add remote_repo_name <remote_repo_path>` add it back as a remote even though the remote already had previously pushed content ?

Comment: Yes it will. why don't you try? there's no risk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

`git remote add` just tells your repository about the remote repository. It doesn't do anything with the *content* of that repo. So `git remote rm` and `git remote add` are inverse operations.

When you do a `git fetch`, git will be smart enough not to download the stuff you already have locally again. This is a consequence of how git works under the hood and not really relevant to your question; you should just know that you've lost nothing by accidentally removing the remote.

Comment: Thanks! Git is fairly new to me, still getting over my fear of the unknowns :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

When you deleted the remote, git just removed it from the list of known remotes (located in `.gitconfig`). Adding it again will do the exact reverse operation.

Your remote references (`origin/master` and such) are not modified in any case, and the fact that you push content doesn't have anything to do.